# Was "Big Lob" originally supposed to be a licensed sports personality?

Tags: casting, gi-joe-the-movie

In the animated *G.I. Joe the Movie*, basketball-player-turned-Joe "Big Lob" (voiced by [Brad Sanders](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0761479/)) is introduced.  He has the number "14" on his jersey.  Hasbro has used licensed personalities as characters in their G.I. Joe line-up before, including Sgt. Slaughter (who featured in said film), Refrigerator Perry, and Rocky Balboa (who was never actually produced).

Was the character of "Big Lob" originally supposed to be a licensed personality, and if so, what happened?

[image]